# Compiled formula is too big to execute (6,091 characters). maximum size is 5,000 characters

Tags: formula-field

I am trying to display a label text based on current scenario
the following field has 1369 characters but I'm getting an error during git commit validation

```
IF(
CONTAINS(TECH_CitizenshipCode__c ,                
$User.Current_Branch_Country__c ) || (TECH_InEECCountries__c && CONTAINS( $CustomMetadata.EECCountries__mdt.EEC_Countries.Country__c , $User.Current_Branch_Country__c)), $Label.WorkPermitActive,
IF(
CONTAINS(TECH_WorkPermit__c , $User.Current_Branch_Country__c) , 
IF(DATEVALUE(MID( TECH_WorkPermit__c , FIND( $User.Current_Branch_Country__c & "-", TECH_WorkPermit__c)+3 , 10))> TODAY() ,
IF((DATEVALUE(MID( TECH_WorkPermit__c , FIND( $User.Current_Branch_Country__c & "-", TECH_WorkPermit__c)+3 , 10))> TODAY()+30) && (CONTAINS(TECH_WorkPermit__c , 'Y-'+$User.Current_Branch_Country__c)), 
$Label.WorkPermitActive,
$Label.WorkPermitExpiringSoon ) ,
IF(CONTAINS(TECH_WorkPermit__c , 'Y-'+$User.Current_Branch_Country__c),$Label.WorkPermitExpiringSoon ,
$Label.WorkPermitInactive)), 
$Label.WorkPermitInactive )
)
```

Comment: are any of the referenced fields also formulas - like `TECH_Workpermit__c` ? or `$User.Current_Branch_Country__c`. This is a common reason why formula size blows up

Comment: no these are not formula .tech_workpermit is a text field and Current_Branch_Country__c has country value stored in it

Comment: @Dodododo If none of the reference fields are formulas the only way around this is to simplify your formula or move it to a flow/process/workflow as they have a much larger formula limit. The compiled size of the formula has almost nothing to do with the source size it is simply that when compiled your formula is more than 5000 characters.

Comment: @KarlLivesey i guess finding an alternate way to update the field is the only option left now